# How to select child element with skipping some of his parents in XPath

Tags: html, xpath

I couldn't find any solution for choosing element using XPath that has many nodes, and we're interested just in reaching one of it's "grand" child (while skipping the others between parent and our destined child node)

i.e. 
If there's a node of: `dialog/form/div/div/div/span/button`

and I'd like to get a short xPath like:
 `//dialog......./button` which would only contain the name of the parent element node (in this case dialog) and the particular grand child element  without stating all the rest nodes that exists between them.

Is there any neat way on how to achieve this?

Comment: `//dialog//button`

Comment: @JLRishe It works fine :), thanks!